# How to debug SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 2031 in prepared statements

Tags: php, pdo, prepared-statement, bindparam

I have this prepared statement query

```
$stmt = $conn->prepare("
        UPDATE language 
        SET lang_alias=:lang_alias , lang_name=:lang_name  
        WHERE lang_id=:lang_id"
);
```

If I set an **array to bind the values**

```
$query_array = array ( ":lang_alias" => "en", ":lang_name" => "English (UK)", ":lang_id" => 1 ) ;
```

and then execute it

```
$stmt->execute(array($query_array));
```

it wont work, I get

> Notice: Array to string conversion`referring to`$stmt->execute(array($query_array));

and `Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number'` referring to the same line.

Then I tried to use **`bindParam` to bind the values**

```
$stmt->bindParam(':lang_alias', $a);
$stmt->bindParam(':lang_name', $c);
$stmt->bindParam(':lang_id', $d3, PDO::PARAM_INT);
```

and works fine

If I try an **alternative `bindParam` syntax**

`$stmt->bindParam("sssiii", $a, $b, $c, $d1, $d2, $d3);`

it wont work. Gives

> Warning: PDOStatement::bindParam() expects at most 5 parameters, 7 given`referring to`$stmt->bindParam("sssiii", $a, $b, $c, $d1, $d2, $d3);

and

> Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 2031 '`referring to`$stmt->execute();

**1.** Is the error caused by the fact that by default prepared statements convert to string all the values, so I have to define the `int` by hand?  Thats why the `bindParam` works fine? Or is it something else that I am missing?

**2.** Why the `bindParam("sssiii"...` sytntax wont work?

**3.** I want this query to get its values dynamically, so using a `bindParam` by hand is not an option. I would like to use an associative array or a `bindParam("sssiii"...` syntax.

How can I do this? Thanks

Comment: @Fred-ii- Done. Still the same error. That was a typo In SO, not in my code.

Comment: @slevin If Chris's comment solved it, maybe invite him to post it as an answer, before someone else pulls the carpet from under his feet ;-)

Comment: @chris85 Yeah, that was it, thanks for pointing it out. The problem with `bindParam("sssiii"...` syntax is still there. I cannot see whats up.

Comment: `sssiii` is mysqli_ syntax, not PDO.

Comment: @Fred-ii- Thanks for the edit.

Comment: @chris85 You're welcome Chris.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `$query_array` is already an array so when you run `$stmt->execute(array($query_array))` you are making into a multidimensional array. This:

```
$stmt->execute($query_array);
```

should be all you need.

As to the `bind` issue you aren't using the `PDO` syntax

- http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.bindparam.php

You are using the `mysqli` syntax with `sssiii`.

- http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php.

Comment: One last thing. So, prepared statements dont have a `bindParam($a, $b, $c)` syntax at all? Thanks

Comment: To the best of my knowledge, no, not in PDO. In PDO the `bindParam` is expecting 1 parameter to be bound.